# Detecting mismatches against constants in scanf format string

Tags: c, io, scanf

From the `man` page of `scanf`:

> A directive is one of the following:
>
> - A sequence of white-space characters (space, tab, newline, etc.; see isspace(3)).  This directive matches any amount of
>     white space, including none, in the input.
> - **An ordinary character (i.e., one other than white space or '%'). This character must exactly match the next character of
>     input.** (emphasis mine)
> - A  conversion specification, which commences with a '%' (percent) character.  A sequence of characters from the input is
>     converted according to this specification, and the result is placed in
>     the corresponding pointer
>               argument.  If the next item of input does not match the conversion specification, the conversion fails—this is a matching
>     failure.

Now, consider the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char* fmt = "A %49s B";
    char buf[50];

    printf("%d\n", sscanf("A foo B", fmt, buf));            // 1
    printf("%d\n", sscanf("blah blaaah blah", fmt, buf));   // 0
    printf("%d\n", sscanf("A blah blah", fmt, buf));        // 1

    return 0;
}
```

Lines 1 and 3 print `1` because matching "A" with "A" succeeds, as does matching "foo"/"blah" with `%s`. Line 2 prints `0` because "A" cannot be matched with "blah", so parsing stops there.

This is all fine and logical, but is there any way for me to detect that a matching failure occurred after all conversion specifications have been successfully matched and assigned? In that case, the value returned by `scanf` will be the number of conversion specifiers in my format string, so I can't use it to tell if matching succeeded till the very end.

In other words: the string fed to `sscanf` in line 3 is not "valid" in the sense that it's not in the format `A [something] B`. Can I use `scanf` to detect this, or is `strtok` my only option?

Comment: Using `sscanf` is not reliable for exact string matching, using a regular expressions library would be more powerful to do the task at hand. For example, *pcre library* or GNU's *regex* library.

Comment: What is your problem? Once finished `sscanf` returns. What additionally do you expect?

Comment: @t0mm13b: Or a simple proper parser potentially with a lexxer. Not enough information given for proper advice.

Comment: @Olaf A parser/lexer combination would be used for more exotic DSL, in the OP's use case is rather simplified and using the combination of parsing/lexing would be overkill.

Comment: Regexp might be, too. See my answer. But I strongly assume OP does not parse "`blah blaaah blah`" so my statement stands: NEI.

Comment: @user4520 Anything more needed on this post?

Answer (score 5):

Employ a `" %n"` at the end of the format.

Directives:
`" "` scans 0 or more white-space.  It does not fail.
`"%n"` saves the count of the number of characters parsed so far (as an `int`).    It does not fail.

Set `n` to 0 and test to see that it changed.  The change would only happen if the entire preceding format succeeded.  Also test that the scan ended on a null character - thus detecting trail unwanted text.

The added `" "`, though optional, if very useful as typically a trailing white-space, which is often a `'\n'`, is not offensive.  It negates the needed for a scanned line of text to be preprocessed to have its line ending removed.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void test(const char *s) {
  const char* fmt = "A %49s B %n";
  char buf[50];
  int n = 0;
  int cnt = sscanf(s, fmt, buf, &n);
  int success = n > 0 && s[n] == '\0';
  printf("sscanf():%2d  n:%2d  success:%d  '%s'\n", cnt, n, success, s);
}

int main(void) {
  test("A foo B");
  test("blah blaaah blah");
  test("A blah blah");
  test("A foo B ");
  test("A foo B x");
  test("");
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
sscanf(): 1  n: 7  success:1  'A foo B'
sscanf(): 0  n: 0  success:0  'blah blaaah blah'
sscanf(): 1  n: 0  success:0  'A blah blah'
sscanf(): 1  n: 8  success:1  'A foo B '
sscanf(): 1  n: 8  success:0  'A foo B x'
sscanf():-1  n: 0  success:0  ''
```

Note that success is determined by `n` alone.  On lack of success, the destination scanned variables like `buf` should not be used.  If a partial result is needed, then use the return value of `sscanf()`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to parse more complex input, use a proper parser/lexxer. Otherwise, have a look at the `%n` [conversion specifier](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.2p12):

> No input is consumed. The corresponding argument shall be a pointer to signed integer into which is to be written the number of characters read from the input stream so far by this call to the fscanf function. Execution of a %n directive does not increment the assignment count returned at the completion of execution of the fscanf function. No argument is converted, but one is consumed. If the conversion specification includes an assignment- suppressing character or a field width, the behavior is undefined.

You can use this multiple times: after the last variable conversion and one at the end.

Answer (score 1):

For OP's use case, `regex` can equally be used to match the pattern.

```
/* see http://linux.die.net/man/3/regex */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <regex.h>

int regexp(const char *);

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    printf("%d\n", regexp("A foo B"));
    printf("%d\n", regexp("blah blaaah blah"));
    printf("%d\n", regexp("A blah blah"));
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
int regexp(const char *input_str){
    char buf[100];
    regex_t regex;
    int rcval;

    /* compile regexp - see http://linux.die.net/man/3/regcomp */
    rcval = regcomp(&regex, "^A\\s.*\\sB$", 0);
    if (rcval) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not compile regex\n");
        return -1;
    }
    /* execute regexp - see http://linux.die.net/man/3/regexec */
    rcval = regexec(&regex, input_str, 0, NULL, 0);
    if (!rcval) {
        fprintf(stdout, "Match\n");
        regfree(&regex);
        return 1;
    }else{
        if (rcval == REG_NOMATCH) {
            fprintf(stdout, "No match\n");
            regfree(&regex);
            return 0;
        }else{
            regerror(rcval, &regex, msgbuf, sizeof(msgbuf));
            fprintf(stderr, "Regex match failed: %s\n", msgbuf);
            regfree(&regex);
            return -1; 
        }
    }
    return 0; // default to no match
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are only interested in whether the entire format has been scanned, but do not care about trailing text in the stream, you can use this terse method:

```
int success = 0;
fscanf(stream, "A %49s B%n", buf, &success);
if(!success) handleError();
```

The trick is, that the `"%n"` conversion does not happen unless the entire format is matched successfully. Since any matching of the format will consume one or more characters from the stream, the value that the `"%n"` writes will always be non-zero. Thus, `success` will be set to a truthy value if, and only if the entire format was matched.